# web3.setProvider is not a function

Tags: testrpc, nodejs

I am trying to learn about web3.js
I install

```
npm install ethereumjs-testrpc
```

and

```
npm install web3  // version 0.20.6
npm install ganache-cli // version 6.0.3
```

then i using the following code

```
var TestRPC = require("ethereumjs-testrpc");
var web3 = require("web3");
var ganache = require("ganache-cli");
//~ web3.setProvider(TestRPC.provider());
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545')); 
//~ var web3 = new web3(web3.givenProvider || ganache.server());

//~ var web3 = new web3(web3.givenProvider || 'ws://some.local-or-remote.node:8546');
//~ web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
//~ web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://geth-node-ip:8545'));
//~ console.log(web3.isAddress("0x8888f1f195afa192cfee860698584c030f4c9db1"))




//~ web3.setProvider(TestRPC.provider());
//~ console.log(web3.version);
//~ console.log(web3.providers);
```

error says `web3.setProvider is not a function`

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want something like this. (Note the capitalization.)

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply i found the solution. testrpc connection is stoped . i am not noticed that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Web 3 version in package.json is

> "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.37"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got the issue, 
According to the docs of [Web3-docs-link](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.8/web3.html) (web3), setProvider() is used to change the provider of the web3, if you are setting the provider for the first time you have to use in this way:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545');
// or
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));

// change provider
web3.setProvider('ws://localhost:8546');
// or
web3.setProvider(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('ws://localhost:8546'));
```